# SQL Query calculates total time worked by user

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a SQL query that can calculate total time Grouped BY USER.

For example: if John Smith does one job for 30 minutes and a different job for 45 minutes creating two records in my database. I need a result that would display

```
USER         Time Worked Total     Date
John Smith           75            XX/XX/XXXX
```

What I have is this.

```
USER         Time Worked Total     Date
John Smith           45            XX/XX/XXXX
John Smith           30            XX/XX/XXXX
```

I can calculate the number of minutes per job done but not the total
Query Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Shipping_Table.Employee, 
  Shipping_Table.Date, 
  DateDiff("n",Shipping_Table.Start_Time,Shipping_Table.End_Time) AS MinutesWorked    
FROM Shipping_Table, Employees    
WHERE Shipping_Table.Date=[Forms]![Time Query]![DateCalc]
```

I am using a form so the USER can just pick a date and check to see how many hours his employees are working. The way the database table is setup the time entries are a Date/Time variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close... just wrap your minutesWorked calculation in a Sum() function and add a group by, and with the group by, you don't need  the distinct.

```
SELECT Shipping_Table.Employee, Shipping_Table.Date, 
      suM(DateDiff("n",Shipping_Table.Start_Time,Shipping_Table.End_Time)) AS MinutesWorked
    FROM Shipping_Table, Employees
    WHERE Shipping_Table.Date=[Forms]![Time Query]![DateCalc]
    GROUP BY Shipping_Table.Employee, Shipping_Table.Date
```

**Note:** your join is missing how shipping_table and employees relate which results in a Cartesian product which can lead to unexpected results.

you should really define how the tables relate to eachother (likely on employeeID and/or date)

Comment: @jpw caught the missing join after I hit save.

Comment: xQbert Thank You! I had tried the Sum of the function and the group by seperately but not together.

Comment: pay attention to the note.. once you are working with multiple employees or dates, you results may not be what you're expecting!  (or eliminate employees table all together as it doesn't appear to be used.)